# How to have multiple config files in c# application?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, class-library

I am developing C# application to write functional test cases using MStest. I have one app.config file. This holds information required in the application. I already added lot of information in the config file. I am accessing these key value pairs in multiple classes.

Now, I want to have multiple config files to my application. All files will be of same structure. For example, If I am running  locally then I want to read values from local.config. If I am running in staging then I want to read it from staging.config. I do not want to change existing code much. Can someone help me to figure out the way to fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environnement variable (like ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ?) in your config file.

So, in your main config file (web.config? app.config?...)

You could include file using the environnement variable as a path in order to select the configs file you want (In c# you can include child config file in a config file use configSource)

configSource="Config\%NAMEOFENV%.config"

Let s me know if it help,